# Issues with http request in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am new to this website, so if i do something wrong please tell me.

I am trying to establish a connection between my node.js server and my android app. For example, I'm trying to connect a page called showWithAuth, where i need to authenticate with digest stategy.

For this purpose i use Authenticator :

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() 
            {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication (username, password.toCharArray());
                    // System.out.println(pa.getUserName() + ":" + new String(pa.getPassword()));
                }
            });
```

My real issue is when i try to establish the connection :

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(strURL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection
                        .getInputStream()));

                String line;

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                System.out.println(sb);
                /*connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                int status = connection.getResponseCode();
                InputStream is;

                if (status >= 400 && status <= 499) {
                    throw new Exception("Bad authentication status: " + status); //provide a more meaningful exception message
                }
                else
                {*/
                    //connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
                    //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

                    /*is = connection.getInputStream();
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
                int readCount;
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                    builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
                }
                String response = builder.toString();
                System.out.println(response);*/

            } catch (java.net.ProtocolException e) {
                sb.append("User Or Password is wrong!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The issue i have is a filenotfoundexception, at this line :`.getInputStream()));`

The response of the server is a 401 : bad authentication status

I saw some people having the same issue i deal with, but i tried every single solution without getting anything better.

If you could help me to get what i do wrong ! Thank you !

PS: the commented code was also tried.

PS2: sorry for being so long.

Edit: Just to say also that this code is working on Netbeans with Java only, but not in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Please try by adding the

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

To your AndroidManifest.xml file, this may solve your problem.

Comment: I've already done this. By the way i have done another app that can connect me to the website via http post, so the website is not the problem, neither my internet connection is